# How can i apply this VBA concatenate to all worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I want to use this code on Active sheet instead of Sheet 1?

```
Sub Concatenate()

' Concatenate two columns
    Dim l As Long, lRow As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For l = 2 To lRow
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(l, 3) = .Cells(l, 1) & " " & .Cells(l, 2)
        Next l
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting Object required error 424 with line: lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I misunderstood. This would apply to all worksheets.

```
Dim l as Long, lRow as Long
For Each ws in Activeworkbook.Worksheets
  With Sheets(ws)
    lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For l = 2 To lRow
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(l, 3) = .Cells(l, 1) & " " & .Cells(l, 2)
    Next l
End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Use this code to apply to the active worksheet only

```
Sub Concatenate()

' Concatenate two columns
Dim l As Long, lRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For l = 2 To lRow
        ActiveSheet.Cells(l, 3) = .Cells(l, 1) & " " & .Cells(l, 2)
    Next l
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: in 6th line starting with 1Row = .Range... error comes up as Object required error 424 Thank you for help

Comment: Use: ActiveSheet

Comment: Thank you all with ActiveSheet code worked perfectly.

Comment: `Rows.Count` refers to the active sheet only. Not that it'll be different for each sheet but if you want to be explicit there should be a sheet object before `Rows`